# libGDX Box2D Turn Around Before Falling From Ground

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

Basicaly I want to make my sprite turn around when reach the end of ground. Look at this screenshot:

[image]

Let say, I want to make the rectangular object turn right before falling. So it just left and right when reach end of the ground.

How to detect that sprite has reach end of the ground?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, so if i did understand you want to detect if your body (box) have reached the end of the ground so you could prevent it from falling down from the ground like the picture
[image]

The  (two) came to mind solutions :
here what i will do i it was for me

1) using position of the body to detect if he reach end or not

```
if(myBody.getposition().x > (x * WORD_TO_BOX2D) {
 // apply force
}else {
 // apply reverse force
}
```

2) adding a transparent fixed body like the picture

[image]

then detecting collision between that fixed body and myBody using

```
world.setContactListener()
```

Hope that was clear and helpful, if not leave a comment
good luck ;=)

Comment: So, I want to make like pattern moving to my enemy. So if I must set transparent fixed body in every end of the platform. It would be so much to work. I will have so many map level.

Comment: when you create your platform (ground) you just have to create another fixture with it, you can also use positions but you need to have to know the right position of each end of the platforms